# How to add a new group and user to that group in Photon OS

Tags: vmware, photon-os

Creating a Docker image from vmware/photon:2.0
I want to run the application inside that container as a user different than root.
So, trying to create a new group and add user to it by following command:

```
groupadd -r new-group && useradd -r -g new-group new-user
```

It throws:

`bash: groupadd: command not found`

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

You can install "shadow" package to be able to add groups/users.

```
tdnf -y install shadow
```

Comment: I had the same error as OP when trying to use groupadd on Photon 3 (minimal), and installing the `shadow` package resolved it.

Answer (score 0):

this is not necessary with Photon:3.0. all the prerequisite tools are ready. That could be because I installed a dep package or was just there.

Comment: The photon:3.0 *docker image* doesn't seem to come with necessary tools by default. However, the full-fledged OS has necessary tools available in-built.
So, when working with docker image of photon:3.0, I had to install the tools explicitly.